# ¿Cómo eliminar archivo SysinfY2X.db?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

No puedo eliminar un archivo en Ubuntu, ya intenté eliminarlo desde la terminal utilizando el comando `rm` y no cede, también utilicé `sudo` y no se elimina. 
El archivo se llama `SysinfY2X.db` y está en el disco sólido de la laptop.

Comment: Es el único archivo que no puedes borrar? Que tal crear archivos o copiar dentro de la carpeta que contiene ese archivo? Alguna posibilidad de que la partición donde está el archivo esté montada como de solo lectura? Agrega a tu pregunta lo que te muestra `sudo mount`

Comment: ¿Que pasa cuando lo intentas? ¿De da error? ¿Que error? ¿Quizas se borre pero algun processo lo vuelve a crear directamente? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y muéstranos i) el error exacto que te da el `rm` y ii) la salida de `ls -li SysinfY2X.db` antes y después de intentar borrarlo.

Answer (score -1):

Por el comentario que pusiste en la respuesta que se te proporcionó, habría que cambiar el tipo de montaje de ese sistema de archivos.

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /
```

En tu terminal, después de eso puedes borrar el archivo. Pero no implica que no haya problemas. Antes trata de reparar posibles problemas con tu sistema de archivos con `fsck -A`

```
fsck /dev/sda1  # Suponiendo ese archivo esta en ese está en ese volumen.
```

Answer (score -2):

Hola buena pregunta ypo te recomiendo utilizar los comandos :

rm -rf SysinfY2X.db

rmdir SysinfY2X.db

Espero que te sirvan

Comment: Utilicé los comandos y no se pudo eliminar el archivo, sale el mensaje "No se puede borrar 'SysinfY2X.db': Sistema de archivos de solo lectura.

Comment: Por favor, no digas a la gente de usar comandos peligrosos sin saber cual es el problema. Si el `SysinfY2X.db` es directorio, el `rm -rf SysinfY2X.db` borrara todo contenido y de manera un poco violenta. No te hace falta el `-f` si no es lo que quieres hacer. Si propones unos comandos, al menos explican que hacen y como funcionen.